# How to pass angular environment variables to javascript script loaded on head section into index.html

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager, environment

I need to pass a Google Tag Manager (GTM) ID from angular environment to javascript script loaded into head section on index.html. This script is tored into a file into assets/js dir.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag("js", new Date());
        gtag("config", "**GTM_ID**");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angular Google tag manager Library. It does this things automatically.

You just have to set the GTM id in the modules imports and then set the GTM id using the service

Check this link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-tag-manager

Or you can declare window at top of your components as any

`declare var window:any`

Comment: Sorry, I put an example, I have to include also facebook pixel and stripe. I need a clean way to include these libs and it's id. From app.component.ts I'm puttind those scripts 

const node1 = document.createElement('script'); // creates the script tag
        node1.src = `https://js.stripe.com/v3/`; // sets the source (insert url in between quotes)
        node1.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        node1.async = true; // makes script run asynchronously
        // append to head of document
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node1);
but I need to pass ids

Comment: stripe recommends add these into index.html

 <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // use your test publishable key
    var elements = stripe.elements();
  </script>

the second script part I put into a file .js into assets/js dir and set node1.src = `./assets/js/stripe.js`;

With this a load stripe but I need pass the real Key from environment angular